# Consuming an iterator in a while loop

Tags: python

I have a function `foo()` that empties out a queue of items, N.B., not a Queue(), just a list of items. The function returns `False` if the list is empty. Is there a disadvantage to using a `while` loop to repeatedly call this function? Simply `pass` in the loop body seems a bit off. Ex:

```
while foo():
    pass
```

Comment: It's fine, but would probably feel cleaner (and easier to test) if there were separate functions for getting an item and processing it. I'm assuming `foo` does something with the items, not just empties a queue and throws them away.

Comment: You should edit your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15114177/python-valid-while-loop-usage) and flag for reopening instead. Note that your question is also rather Non Constructive; you are asking for opinions more than anything.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know I could ask for re-opening, with the swiftness of my punishment in regards to that question, I thought it was a done deal. There was also a comment in favor of re-opening that was deleted, and I was still curious to an actual answer. The answer that I have now is that there seem to be no serious objections, so I'm glad.

Comment: This question is now not a duplicate, as the 'original' does not exist anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This form may be easier to understand:

```
while items:
    foo()
```

Answer (score 0):

`all(foo())` will consume items from an iterator until it receives a falsey value (or until the iterator is exhausted).